# How to load outlook item (.msg) file format attachment to hive table?

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, bigdata, azure-hdinsight

First of all, I am using Microsoft Azure HDinsight hadoop.

I have .msg file attachments(mail message format for Outlook) 
I already upload to my blob storage but I can not upload them to table that I have created. Is there way I can upload them to the existing table? Any advice will help. Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hive does not understand msg format so you will have to read it as a string and then write a query on it to read from the blob store and then insert it into the table. You can either use space as a delimiter and/or write your own custom extractor using Java or Python to insert it into the table.